Does "sola fide" have any Biblical support if Paul's "works of the law" is just referring to the Mosaic ceremonial law?
I've been digging into "the new perspectives on Paul" and thinking that many of the "new perspectives" seem like, or lead to, traditional Catholic/Orthodox perspectives on Justification. Specifically, the idea that when Paul refers to "works of the law," he is referring exclusively to the ceremonial aspects of the Mosaic law. This would seem to shatter all the Protestant go-to verses that supposedly prove sola fide.
TLDR:
If you read "works of the law" to mean works of the ceremonial Mosaic law (i.e., circumcision) exclusively, then what is left to support the doctrine of sola fide aside from Luther's Occam-inspired philosophy?

Seventh Day Adventists have a good explaination for this...that Solar fide claims that whilst we are saved by faith, it is the "fruits of faith" that makes us want to uphold the law. It has nothing to do with tue idea the law saves us, but everything to do with Christs sometimes made statement after healing people, "go and sin no more". He clearly linked the idea of faith with a change in behaviour...a wanting to do good things.

The Mosaic law includes all kinds of moral stipulations including love your neighbor as yourself (Lev. 19:18), so even if "works of the Law" is limited to works of the Mosaic law, it doesn't make sense to say it's only some arbitrary subset of them such as circumcision.

Hi, Dark Malthrop. This is an interesting insight; thank you for your input. However, there is a distinction between ceremonial law and moral law. What Paul references as "works of the law" always falls under the category of "ceremonial law." I'm not sure if you are familiar with any of the "new perspectives" that I am referencing; what you are stating would be considered a traditional protestant reading, as far as I understand.

No such distinction is made within the Old or New Testament as far as I am aware; it's a heuristic invented by commentators to help navigate the question of what laws from the Mosaic Law are we expected to obey in the New Covenant. I am familiar with NPP but I think it's almost wholly without basis.

@Displayname says "I'm not sure if you are familiar with any of the "new perspectives" that I am referencing". You could add a summary of it, or at least a link, to the question, then even those of us that can't answer the question might at least learn something from it.

The problem is that Paul says 'law' and means 'law'. Only those who want him to say 'ceremonial law' see the words 'ceremonial law' on the page. This is a common occurrence in regard to reading the bible.

I mean I'd love to respond, but this is asking for a protestant response. I think the NPP are getting closer to my eastern orthodoxy, and starting to understand that sola fide is... wrong.

@Wyrsa taking a look at the notes in my Orthodox Study Bible, I think that the Orthodox reading of Paul is more akin to Protestants than to NPP, as it does not appear to interpret "works of the law" in that restricted sense. There is certainly a difference between Orthodox and Protestant soteriology, but it lies in a more subtle question of the relationship between works, law, and justification, and not on the definition of "law" in Paul. Correct me if I'm mistaken.

Don't have time to write a proper answer, but I would base it on this lecture to a Reformed church audience by one npp proponent NT Wright who stays Protestant and believe in sola fide (though in a DIFFERENT meaning than how it is popularly constructed).  Also see Richard Cara's argument against a form of npp.

@DarkMalthorp I tend to search for what the church fathers said about specific verses if possible, the orthodox study Bible is a good basis, those study notes could have been better though... we should remember that Paul was also dealing with a bunch of people who thought you still needed to circumcise to be "justified" to the new faith.

True, but to fixate on that ignores a key part of his argument. Gal5:3 is as much to say, "if you think circumcision is required for justification, actually you ought to think that about the whole law." And he makes the point elsewhere repeatedly that no-one perfectly obeys the whole law, so if that is the grounds of justification, we aren't getting justified! OSB makes the same point in the footnote on Gal.3:10. Regarding the fathers, I haven't read anything in them that sounds like NPP. According to Wikipedia, those Catholics who look hardest at the fathers are also the most skeptical of NPP

I plan to write a detailed answer to this when I have time.

Why doesn't Ephesians 2:8-9 answer this question?

Sola Fide is a position based on a peculiar and curious interpretation. The objection that the works of the law arguments by Paul refer to the Moses law covenant, rather than human efforts or all works, does not put a stop to it.
The proponents of faith alone typically substantiate their view by shifting the focus to faith being roots and works as fruits (cause and effect relation), and also about the attitude of doing works to be something other than for justification, though works remain optional under their soteriology. These two arguments are seen in their response to the topic of James 2 which explains faith alone is dead without works. They'd say that James is explaining genuine faith rather than justification.

Works are not optional.  Better to say that under Sola Fida they are inevitable.

They are indeed optional since they're not essential. Being inevitable doesn't make it essential. Since they believe good deeds don't count for justification, it follows that bad deeds don't harm them for justification either.

It ceases to be faith alone in the cause effect relation of faith works. Though it's the main position of defense.

Make a tree good and its fruit will be good, or make a tree bad and its fruit will be bad, for a tree is recognized by its fruit.  Not "might be" good.  Will be good.  Not an option ... just a result.  Good deeds are the result of justification.  Neither our good nor bad deeds avail one of it.  That is Christ who has availed it for us.

Yes there is biblical basis for Sola Fide because in his letter to the Ephesians Paul rules out human effort of any kind in any arena playing any role in accessing salvation:

But God, who is rich in mercy, for his great love wherewith he loved us, Even when we were dead in sins, hath quickened us together with Christ, (by grace ye are saved;) And hath raised us up together, and made us sit together in heavenly places in Christ Jesus: That in the ages to come he might shew the exceeding riches of his grace in his kindness toward us through Christ Jesus. For by grace are ye saved through faith; and that not of yourselves: it is the gift of God: Not of works, lest any man should boast. For we are his workmanship, created in Christ Jesus unto good works, which God hath before ordained that we should walk in them. - Ephesians 2:4-10

Salvation is addressed, by Paul (bolded above), in perfect tense:  Already completed past action with present effect.  The other verbs are in aorist tense (italics): Deliberate silence about when the action takes place or how long it would last.
This already completed salvation is accessed through faith.  Faith is the vehicle, if you will, the means by which the grace of God offered in already completed salvation is accessed:

The preposition δια (dia) means through or throughout. Connected to appropriate verbs it may express the traversing of a place, or the experiencing of a time period. It may be used to indicate the instrument with which something is brought about (by means of, or via) or the mode, manner or circumstances (on account of) and even for what reason or out of which motivation.

It is not accessed by (from) works and the given reason for it not being accessed this way is to eliminate any justification for human boasting:

The preposition or prefix εκ (ek, or εξ ex when followed by a vowel) means of or from when a situation is described in which an object or person becomes separated from what it was previously one with; it's the opposite of εις (eis), meaning in or into.

Works, as used here by Paul in an unspecified fashion, describes any or every human effort.  It simply means labor, a doing, or a thing done.  When coupled in a phrase like "works of the Law" it may mean all of the Law or some subset of the Law as this OP asks after.  As used in Ephesians, though, it simply means any and every human effort and so encompasses all of the "works of the law" regardless of whether it is viewed in it's entirety or broken into bits.
Salvation is by grace through faith unto preordained good works.  It is the gift of God accessed through the vehicle of faith with the expressed purpose of producing beneficial, virtuous labor:

The preposition επι (epi) means on, upon or unto. It survives in English in words such as epilogue (upon, or after the main story), epidermis (upper skin) and epicenter (the point on the earth's surface directly above an earthquake).  Our preposition is used in a great variety of ways, some implying rest (being physically located upon or logically completing a statement) and others implying motion (moving onto a location or toward a situation or understanding).

Having accessed salvation through faith and faith alone (Sola Fide) in what God has graciously done for us in Christ Jesus, virtuous human effort is now possible through Him who strengthens us.  Even then we have no grounds for boasting because it is God who works in us to will and to do of His good pleasure:

Wherefore, my beloved, as ye have always obeyed, not as in my presence only, but now much more in my absence, work out your own salvation with fear and trembling. For it is God which worketh in you both to will and to do of his good pleasure. - Philippians 2:12-13

God works internally within us and we effectuate it ... we work out what God works in.  This places "works" within the realm of sanctification which is the product of, and never the means to, salvation.
